# Automatic cascading placement of graphics

Tags: graphics, image, grid-layouts

Is it possible to automatically cascade graphics or images in MMA? It seems to me that most of the built-in graphic functions have a gridded style, e.g., `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow`, and `GraphicsColumn`. The best approach that I have found so far is to use `ImageCompose` and then systematically change the overlay position. Can anyone think of a more straightforward way to do this?

By cascading, I mean a structure like this:
[image]

Comment: `Show[ . . . ]`? (Without more details about what you mean by "cascade", these two suggestions are the best we can do. Can you explain what you mean?_

Comment: I don't think they have any options for automatically cascading the placements, right? So in your opinion, at the end, it comes to programming the positions manually?

Comment: @march does this image help? Maybe "cascading" can be defined as "angled grids with a previously-defined overlap"?

Comment: Are these plots going to be transparent so you can see the ones behind? Or are you actually wanting the plots to open in different windows in this cascaded form? (If the former, my best guess is you need to hard-code it. There's no built-in function as far as I know.)

Comment: Yeah you guessed right. I want them transparent . Thanks a lot for your inputs. I wanted to make sure before putting the time to hard-code it.

Comment: Just slightly related: `FrontEndTokenExecute["StackWindows"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would reproduce the picture you show in the question:

```
With[{off = 30},
 Do[
  CreateDocument[{Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, Pi}]}, 
   WindowSize -> {300, 200}, WindowOpacity -> .7, 
   WindowMargins -> {{100 + off i, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
      10 + off i}}],
  {i, 1, 10}]]
```

[image: frames]

I added opacity as per the comment.

Comment: This works. Great, Thanks!